# Sqoop HDFS to Couchbase: json file format

Tags: json, hadoop, hdfs, couchbase, sqoop

I'm trying the export data form HDFS to Couchbase and I have a problem with my file format.

My configuration:

- Couchbase server 2.0
- Stack hadoop cdh4.1.2
- sqoop 1.4.2 (compiled with hadoop2.0.0)
- couchbase/hadoop connector (compiled with hadoop2.0.0)

When I run the export command, I can easily export files with this kind of format:

```
id,"value"
```

or

```
id,42
```

or

```
id,{"key":"value"}
```

But when I want to apply a Json object it doesn't work!

```
id,{"key1":"value1,"key2":"value2"}
```

The content is truncated at the first comma and diplay in base64 by couchbase because now the content is not a correct JSON...

So, my question is how the file must by formated to be stored as a json document?

Can we only export a key/value file?

I want to export json files form HDFS like the **cbdocloader** do it with files from local file system...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this expected behavior as Sqoop is parsing your input file as CSV with comma as a separator. You might need tweak your file format to either escape separator or enclose entire JSON string. I would recommend reading how exactly Sqoop is dealing with escaping separators and enclosing strings in the user guide [1].

Links:

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#id387098

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to convert the files to tab-delimited, if you're still working on this. If you look at the Sqoop documentation (http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_large_objects), there's an option --fields-terminated-by which allows you to specify which characters Sqoop splits fields on.

If you passed it --fields-terminated-by '\t', and a tab-delimited file, it would leave the commas in place in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

@mpiffaretti can you post your sqoop export command? I think each JSON object should have its own key value. 
    `key1    {"dataOne":"ValueOne"}`
`key2    {"dataTwo":"ValueTwo"}`
http://ajanacs.weebly.com/blog
In your case change the datea  like below may help you solve the issue.

```
id,{"key":"value"}
 id2,{"key2":"value2"}
```

Let me know if you have further questions on it.
[json] [sqoopexport] [couchbase]